# Thread1 signal SIGABRT says NSInvalid Argument Exception

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exception, sigabrt

I had this error and I couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code. Here is what the console window says, but the code was fine before, and the new thing I added has nothing to do with the code it says. Can anyone understand what is wrong?
here is what Xcode tells me :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which
>   already has a parent:  name:'(null)'
>   texture:[ 'balloon' (100 x 91)] position:{-144, 600}
>   scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{100, 91} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'

also, my code:

```
 private var label : SKLabelNode?
    private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?
    var flyingPig:SKSpriteNode!
    var water = SKSpriteNode()
    var scoreLabel :SKLabelNode!

    var totalTime = 0

    {
        didSet{
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(totalTime) km"
        }
    }

    struct PhysicsCategories{

    static let pig : UInt32 = 0b1
    static let aFish : UInt32 = 0b100
}

var timer : Timer!
var timing : Timer!
var fish = ["bluedy","lantern","balloon","Knife"]



var lives:[SKSpriteNode]!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    water = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "water")

    water.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y:0)

    water.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: water.size)

    water.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    water.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    self.addChild(water)

    flyingPig = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"FlyingPig")
    flyingPig.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
    flyingPig.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: flyingPig.size)
    flyingPig.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity=false
    flyingPig.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.pig
    flyingPig.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.aFish
    self.addChild(flyingPig)

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx:0,dy:0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text:"Score: 0")
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x:-290,y:600)
    scoreLabel.fontName = "PartyLetPlain"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 44
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1,target:self,selector:#selector(addFish),userInfo:nil,repeats:true)
    timing = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    addLives()


}


func addLives()
{
    lives = [SKSpriteNode()]
    for live in 1...3{
        let liveNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"FlyingPig2")
        liveNode.position = CGPoint(x:350-CGFloat(4-live)*liveNode.size.width,y:610)
        self.addChild(liveNode)
        lives.append(liveNode)
    }
}

func addFish()
{
    fish = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: fish) as![String]

    let aFish = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: fish[0])

    let fishPosition = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue:-300, highestValue:300)
    let position = CGFloat(fishPosition.nextInt())
    aFish.position=CGPoint(x:position,y:600)

    aFish.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: aFish.size)
    aFish.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    aFish.physicsBody?.isDynamic=true
    aFish.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.aFish

    aFish.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.pig
    self.addChild(aFish)

    let nemo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "nemo")

    let nemoPosition = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue:-300, highestValue:300)
    let nposition = CGFloat(nemoPosition.nextInt())
    nemo.position=CGPoint(x:nposition,y:600)

    nemo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: aFish.size)
    nemo.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    nemo.physicsBody?.isDynamic=true



    self.addChild(aFish)
    self.addChild(nemo)

    let animationDuration:TimeInterval = 4
    var actionArray = [SKAction]()
    actionArray.append(SKAction.move(to:CGPoint(x:position,y:-800),duration:animationDuration))
    aFish.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
        }





func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var body1 = SKPhysicsBody()
    var body2 = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask{
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    }
    else{
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }

    if body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.pig && body2.categoryBitMask==PhysicsCategories.aFish
    {
        body2.node?.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431009/error-attemped-to-add-a-sknode-which-already-has-a-parent)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding one child twice

```
self.addChild(aFish)

....


self.addChild(aFish)
self.addChild(nemo)
```

Just remove one call and it should be okay.